# stopPropagation not preventing bubbling with Bootstrap popover

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, jquery-events, stoppropagation

I am attempting to prevent clicks on a React Bootstrap popover from bubbling up and triggering the `onClick` handler on a parent element. Using the standard `event.stopPropagation()` does not, in fact, stop propagation, nor does its native counterpart:

[Please see the working reduced test case on JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/gavage/edit?js,output)

My current approach (within the parent's `onClick` event) is to check if the target element is inside the popover's DOM tree (using [jQuery.has](https://api.jquery.com/has/) for convenience):

```
function onParentClicked(e) {
    if (!$(this.refs.parentElement).has(e.target)) {
        // click did NOT originate from popover
    }
}
```

This approach mostly works, but seems like a hacky workaround for simply using `stopPropagation` in the child's `onClick` handler.

Is this possibly a React Bootstrap bug? Or am I missing something in how I should be handling this logic?

Comment: This is 18 months later, but when I click the button in your fiddle, the message says "nothing clicked yet" and the popover opens, which I think is what you want? So I take it this has been fixed in react-bootstrap now?

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting `Popover` outside the parent `div`?